# Infinite login loop after upgrading from 15.10 to 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, upgrade, 15.10, 16.04

I got infinite login loop after upgraded from 15.10 to 16.04. I have a dell 8700 desktop with Nvidia GTX 960 video card. I have tried nvidia-361 or nvidia-364, both have the same problem. 
I have to purge the Nvidia driver to successfully login. But the open source video card driver seems not support multiple monitor.

here is my .xsession-errors:

```
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
upstart: gnome-session (Unity) main process (2228) terminated with status 1
upstart: unity-settings-daemon main process (2221) killed by TERM signal
upstart: logrotate main process (2063) killed by TERM signal
upstart: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_bin_fcitx.1000.crash) main process (2131) killed by TERM signal
upstart: update-notifier-crash (/var/crash/_usr_share_software-center_software-center.1000.crash) main process (2132) killed by TERM signal
upstart: hud main process (2219) killed by TERM signal
upstart: unity-panel-service main process (2234) killed by TERM signal
upstart: Disconnected from notified D-Bus bus
upstart: bamfdaemon main process (2130) killed by TERM signal
```

Answer (score 0):

The proprietary driver does not start with Secure Boot on.

You can fix it by running

```
sudo apt install mokutil
sudo mokutil --disable-validation
```